# laravel 5 : Extend a Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I need to handle different types of DB depending on the client.

I created a Facade called *MyDBFacade* where I can call my own functions.

For example:

```
MyDBFacade::createDBUser("MyUser"); // will create a DB user whatever I'm using Postgres or SQL Server
```

Is there a possibility to extends the framework Facade **DB::** in a way I could add my own functions and then call `DB::createUser("MyUser")` ?

Any clue or idea would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say that you define your custom facade in `app/Facades/MyDBFacade.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MyDBFacade extends DB
{
    // ...
}
```

You just need to change single line in `config/app.php`, from

```
'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
```

to

```
'DB' => App\Facades\MyDBFacade::class,
```

And it all should work now.

Comment: One quick note, from within the `Facade` "extension" class you are creating, it would appear that you cannot call the original `Facade` by name. Instead, you must use the current classname, or because of this, perhaps more semantically clear would be using `self::`.

Comment: @Paul can we define non static methods in `MyDBFacade` class & use as static methods ?

Comment: Hey! I don't really know, haven't been using Laravel since about the time I wrote this. I recommend to try ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can create / extend your Facade like this:

```
<?php namespace YourNameSpace\Facades;

class MyDBFacade extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB {

        /**
         * Create your custom methods here...
         */
        public static function anyMethod($active)
        {
            /// do what you have to do
        }

}
```

And then replace (or add it as a new one) to your `app/config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => array(
  'MyDBFacade'   =>  'YourNameSpace\Facades\MyEventFacade::class',
),
```

Remember to execute `composer dump-autoload` at the end.

Hope this helps!