# How to extend Laravel Log::info() (without making a new class)?

Tags: laravel, logging

I know I can extend it as follows:

```
class MyLog extends Logs {
  ...
}
```

But, I don't want to do this as I have a plethora of `Log::info()` in my project in different places.

Can I extend `Log::info()` without making a new class MyLog?

Comment: extend how? what are you trying to do? `Log` is a facade, it just uses the `log` binding on the container

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615078/990164 is helpful, but it is with another class name.

Comment: I need to keep the usage same with Log::info class-name.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ... why are you trying to extend this or change it? what is the functionality you need to change about it?

Comment: I need to exclude some specific info from logged message. For example password, phone-number, api-token etc.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is using Monolog for logging which you can add processors to that can manipulate the `record` before it gets sent to the different handlers for logging.

For now in the `boot` method of a Service Provider you could try:

```
\Log::pushProcessor(function ($record) {
    /*
    record array contains keys:
        message, context, level, level_name, channel, datetime, extra
     */

    // do what you need to return your filtered record
    return $record;        
});
```